# Specify associated type of parent protocol in child protocol with Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

In Swift 2, I have a protocol:

```
protocol Protocol {
    typealias Type
}
```

When I want to use `Protocol` without defining what type to use for `Type`:

```
var protocol1: Protocol
```

Then I'm getting the following error:

> Protocol 'Protocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

It is clear why this is not going to work.

---

I have another protocol, which inherits from the first protocol and specifies that the associated type `Type` should be a `String`.

```
protocol AnotherProtocol: Protocol {
    typealias Type = String
}
```

The same error occurs, when I try to use this protocol:

```
var protocol2: AnotherProtocol
```

> Protocol 'AnotherProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Why am I getting an error for this, although I have specified the associated type?

**Is there another way for the second protocol to specify the associated type of the parent protocol, without having to specify it again in every class that implements the second protocol?**

Answer (score 2):

Your error isn't coming from the declaration or definition of your protocols, it comes from how you're trying to use them. There are two basic ways you can use a protocol: as a pseudo-type, or as a constraint. When you declare a variable like this:

```
var protocol1: Protocol
```

You're using the protocol like it's a type: the type of `protocol1` is `Protocol`. This is different from using it as a constraint. *Other types* conform to the protocol if it's used as a constraint:

```
struct SomeStruct: Protocol {...
```

Now, you can use your protocols in either way, but there are some disadvantages to both ways. Firstly, you can't store a heterogenous collection of "protocols as a constraint", whereas you can when you use protocols as a type.

Secondly, if there are requirements on self or associated types, you can no longer use that protocol as a type.

So, here's what I think you're looking for. Your first protocol:

```
protocol Protocol {
  typealias Type
}
```

And then the second:

```
protocol InheritingProtocol {
  typealias Type = String
}
```

Now, if you want something to conform to the second protocol, it must be used as a constraint. That means that some *type* conforms to the protocol, and then you can have some *instance* of that type.

```
struct SomeType : InheritingProtocol {}

let someInstance = SomeType()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to pass around the second protocol without having to know about a class/struct that implements the protocol. But as you said, using the protocol as a type is not possible if it has associated types. The second protocol has an associated type, but it is clear, what type this is. That's what I think is strange. Using this protocol as a type should be possible, because all associated types are declared.

Comment: You could use a type-erased wrapper

Comment: Unfortunately, a class that implements the second protocol needs to have a superclass. So it have to implement the protocol and cannot subclass another class, but with type-erased wrappers I have to use created classes.

Comment: @Marian did you find out how to implement this?